# Anonymous Complain-Suggestion Box SharePoint 2013

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, web-part, sharepoint-addin

I want to create an anonymous feedback form in SharePoint 2013 for internal complaints and feedback. Anonymous to the level even site administrators should not be able to know who posted.

Comment: Even if you develop a fully custom user interface and then add the item programmatically while running the code in an elevated context (so that any change will be marked as 'System'), an evil site administrator could abuse the audit features to see **who** accessed the "New Complaint" page and **when**. Unless you foresee a lots of complaints coming in, it would be pretty easy to determine who posted what when. I fear that the only solution is a small site with just the list where users will post the complains and anonymous access enabled.

Comment: Other option worth trying is to enable anonymous access to the "custom user interface" that I was suggesting at the start, but I still believe that you may leave some users activity track in the audit logs.

Comment: yeah, I think the later is more robust. I'll give that a shot. thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you use a survey.  This will take you all of about 2 minutes to setup.

From the overview.aspx page, go to 'Setting' > 'Survey Settings' > 'List name, description and navigation'.

Under survey options use 'Show user names in survey results.

Is it possible to crack this open and see the real names?  Probably, but I would think it would be difficult.

Answer (score 1):

I tried to tackle this with my organization last year.

If you're looking for a super simple option, I would use an excel survey, which can be created from within a sharepoint document library that allows external sharing. To the best of my knowledge, there is no way to figure out who submitted what.

I also considered using an infopath form and list with an attached workflow that had an impersonation step with a copy from one list to another and delete function that would erase the submission from the person who created the complaint within about a minute by deleting that item from the first list. The only risk to this is that if the workflow breaks, non-anonymous submissions could back up in that first list.